# Apache 2 Expect </Directory> but saw </VirtualHost>

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I'm trying to install DAViCal+CalDavZap in Debian 8.0. And have this problem:

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dav.conf:

```
 # Virtual Host def for Debian packaged DAViCal
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /usr/share/davical/htdocs
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
ServerName davical.local
Alias /images/ /usr/share/davical/htdocs/images/
Alias /cal /var/www/caldavzap/
<Directory /usr/share/davical/htdocs/>
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
php_value include_path /usr/share/awl/inc
php_value magic_quotes_gpc 0
php_value register_globals 0
php_value error_reporting «E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE»
php_value default_charset «utf-8»
</VirtualHost>
```

and sudo service apache2 restart:

```
Syntax error on line 18 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dav.conf: Expected </Directory> but saw </VirtualHost>
Action 'start' failed.
```

Can you say me what could it be, what should i check, please?